# Get distinct values sorted by date_posted in decending order with PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Below is the query I used

```
jd = mongo.db.rest_manage_job_format
```

`Type_of_request = jd.find().distinct("Type_of_request").sort('date_posted',-1`)

but it gives me TypeError:

```
TypeError: must use keyword argument for key function
```

i have no idea how to solve it.Please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try aggregation here `Type_of_request = (await jd.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$Type_of_request",
    "date_posted": { "$first": "$date_posted" }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "date_posted": 1 }}
])).map(({ _id }) => _id)`

Answer (score 2):

The `.distinct` method returns a list and the `sort` method here is the `list.sort` method which takes keyword arguments only.

If you want to sort your element by "date_posted", you need to use the `.aggregate` method or pass a function to `key` when you call `list.sort`

Answer (score 0):

distinct() returns a list, you have to sort the list

```
jd = mongo.db.rest_manage_job_format

Type_of_request = jd.find().distinct("Type_of_request").sort(reverse=True)
```